# ¿Cómo generar múltiples pdfs dependiendo del id a través de un foreach?

Tags: php, html, foreach, jspdf

Tengo una línea de código que genera un pdf y me salta este aviso:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /system/recycled/pdf-print-get.php on line 32 no pdf's was generated

este es el código que genera el pdf.

```
// get pdf

$data=array();
foreach($id as $id_tmp):
foreach($watermark as $v):

    $returned=get_pdf_from_template($path,$template,$options,$v,array("id"=>$id_tmp));

    if(!$returned["status"]){
    die($returned["msg"]." , revise que haya sido generado y timbrado el xml");

    }

    $data[]=$returned["data"];

endforeach;
endforeach;

// ...

if(!$data)
die("no pdf's was generated.");
```

Sólo genera un pdf único, no genera el pdf dependiendo del id, alguna sugerencia de como hacer para que genere el pdf correcto, trato de meterlo en un forech ($regs as $v){   pero me oculta la etiqueta img.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo "$sys[url]_resources/scripts/php/system/recycled/pdf-print-get.php?id=$id[id]&id_payment=&path=%2Fopt%2Flampp%2Fhtdocs%2Fcustomer%2Fdisa% target="_blank"> <img class='i-q'>&nbsp;</a>     esta  es la linea para el pdf

Answer (score 0):

Para generar PDF con php tienes varias opciones, entre ellas:

**FPDF**
La clase FPDF está escrita en PHP4 y fue el primer script PHP para la creación de archivos PDF de forma dinámica. Funciona con PHP4 y PHP5.

**TCPDF**
Este proyecto ea un script para generación de archivos PDF basado en la librería FPDF. Inicialmente fue una versión para PHP5 con soporte UTF-8 pero se ha convertido en un proyecto independiente el cual tiene gran soporte para imágenes, incluso para colores CMYK.

**Zend_Pdf**
El framework Zend tiene una clase para la generación de archivos PDF, la cual tiene menos funciones que FPDF y otras clases. La documentación de esta clase, como muchas de Zend, es muy limitada. Si usa el framework Zend en su proyecto, es muy recomendable usar esta clase.

**PDFlib**
La librería PDFlib es la solución comercial para la generación de archivos PDF con PHP. Cuando se instala (compilada), puede empezar a usarse de forma inmediata en el código PHP sin necesidad de incluir otras clases o librerías. Es una librería bastante buena y rápida aunque su costo es un poco alto.

Para tu problema con la etiqueta img, te adjunto la sintaxis:
`Image(string file [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, string type [, mixed link]]]]]])`